# Assets and JavaScript debugging

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, symfony, asset-pipeline, assetic

Most of modern frameworks contain asset managers (Rails, Symfony, etc).
Some of asset managers combine scripts, move, link and rename them.

Could you tell me the way to use Javascript debugger(e.g. PhpStorm, RubyMine) if my files are moved and renamed by asset manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two words : Source maps. Source maps allow you to get your files compiled, moved, renamed, concatenated, etc, and still keep the correct source location information.

I'm not sure if Sprockets, Assetic etc. provide it, but there are several javascript build tools that can handle it (I think grunt and brunch do).

Comment: Could you give an example of mapping string with mapping of compiled files from assets to project files?

Comment: It seems not much big projects compile them correctly. But as you can see [in a .map file](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/blob/master/angular.min.js.map#L6), `sources` is an array.

Comment: You can check out [This grunt plugin](https://github.com/tarruda/grunt-coffee-build) which does correct source map concat of coffee sources.